# Multiprocessing convert S3 content body to pandas DataFrame AWS Sagemaker

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, amazon-s3, python-multiprocessing, amazon-sagemaker

In a conda_python3 notebook of AWS SageMaker, I have defined the following function that turns the S3 object content into a data frame:

```
import io
import pandas as pd
def readS3Csv(corpus):
    df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(corpus['Body'].read()))
    print(str(corpus) + ' read')
    return(df)
```

I tested it with:

```
corpus1 = s3.get_object(Bucket='XXXX', Key='ZZZZ')
x = readS3Csv(corpus1)
```

And it worked well so far. Then I tried to paralellize the conversion of content to DataFrame for the content in different S3 objects:

```
corpus1 = s3.get_object(Bucket='XXX', Key='QQQ')
corpus2 = s3.get_object(Bucket='XXX', Key='EEE')
corpus3 = s3.get_object(Bucket='XXX', Key='KKK')
corpus4 = s3.get_object(Bucket='XXX', Key='ZZZ')
```

I used the multiprocessing library as:

```
corpus = [corpus1,corpus2,corpus3,corpus4,corpus5,corpus6]
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes = 6)

dfs = pool.map(readS3Cvs, corpus)
```

I got this error:

> TypeError: cannot serialize '_io.BufferedReader' object

Then I tried:

```
with multiprocessing.Pool() as p:
    print(p.map(readS3Csv, corpus))
```

And I still got the same error.

Then I tried including the s3.get object inside the defined function as:

```
import io
import pandas as pd
import boto3

def readS3Csv(key):
    s3 = boto3.client(
            's3',
            aws_access_key_id='HHH',
            aws_secret_access_key='ZZZ'
        )
    corpus = s3.get_object(Bucket='XXX', Key=key)
    df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(corpus['Body'].read()))
    print(str(key) + ' read')
    return(df)
```

And when I run:

```
keys = ['ttt','uuu','rrr','iii']
dfs = readS3Csv(keys[0])
```

I get the dataframe with no erros. But when I do

```
keys = ['ttt','uuu','rrr','iii']
dfs = pool.map(readS3Csv,keys)
```

But I am still getting an error:

> Reason: 'error("'i' format requires -2147483648 <= number <= 2147483647",)'

Answer (score 1):

s3.get_object returns a dict containing StreamingBody which cannot be serialized since its nothing but a wrapper for a stream reader. For multiprocessing to work, the parameters to the worker processes need to be serializable.

Since your bucket name is constant, you should pass in the key name to readS3Csv() and do s3.get_object inside that method rather than passing in the corpus.

Comment: I pass in the key name to readS3Csv() and do s3.get_object inside that method, it merely works with the method and one element, but when I try to parallelize the process I get a different error. I modified the question; you can see the error above

Comment: now you have a problem on the output side :) . Since your readS3Csv() method is returning a dataframe, your processes are trying to return that. Both the input and output to/from worker processes needs to be serializable.

Try using df.to_dict / df.to_pickle / df.to_msgpack and return that.

Comment: I tried using df.to_dict(), and I got the same problem on the output side. I am not sure about to_pickle() and to_msgpack() because that will mean that I have to store them somewhere and it will have to be an S3 file. I will need to embed a boto3.put_object function somewhere.

Comment: Nevertheless, I solved my first error with your advice thanks!